# Excel Multiple Drop-Boxes

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, xls, vlookup

I am trying to created a spreadsheet with two drop boxes where 1=Name 2=Month. I am trying to make it so that if you choose the month and name it will display the corresponding data. Can someone please help with the best way to do this? Please let me know if I need to elaborate more on my issue. Since I can't upload a photo...I've tried to provide and example below for clarification. I was able to get it to work with using only one drop box using Vlookup but I'm not having much luck with incorporating the 2nd Dropbox. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
              John        Adam        Rob   
            Win Lost    Win Lost    Win Lost
January      15    1     50    3     30    5
February     20    2     45    2     35    4
March        25    3     40    1     10    6

Name    Adam                    
Month   February                    
Win       45                    
Lost       2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) on your data matrix. Peel out the row and column with the [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca). Offset the range you are looking for by one column to get the *Lost* from essentially the same formula as the *Win*.

[image: Win Lost Drop-Downs]

The formula in B9 is,

```
=INDEX($B$3:$F$5, MATCH(B$8, A$3:A$5, 0), MATCH(B$7, B$1:G$1, 0))
```

The formula in B10 is,

```
=INDEX($C$3:$G$5, MATCH(B$8, A$3:A$5, 0), MATCH(B$7, B$1:G$1, 0))
```

The values in B7 & B8 are Data Validation Lists using `=$B$1:$F$1` and `=$A$3:$A$5` as the *Source:*.

Comment: Works perfectly thanks very much Jeeped! (P.S. this site has some crazy rules...i can't even 1UP you without reputation because I'm new to the site?!) Hi-Five